# How to run a powershell script without the window showing up

Tags: powershell, hidden

[Task Scheduler Hide Button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpCEJ.png)

The answer, to some, is to run a scheduled task in Windows by invoking powershell.exe, then your arguments, or just invoke the whole script and then make the task hidden.

I see this working just fine. Do you see any drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

- on windows folder navigation bar give parameter -windowstyle hidden
- i.e. running jupyterlab service:
  `PowerShell.exe -windowstyle hidden jupyter lab --ip localhost --port 8888`